# How To Get Get-ADUser To Return Individual Properties

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to clean up this code.  Isn't there a way to do something like this?

```
$CurrentUserDetails = Get-ADuser -Identity $CurrentUserName -Properties *
$CurrentUserDetails.LastName (<-- This does not work.)
```

Instead of having to do this? (The below works)

```
$CurrentFirstName = (Get-ADuser -Identity $CurrentUserName -Properties GivenName).GivenName
$CurrentLastName = (Get-ADuser -Identity $CurrentUserName -Properties SurName).SurName
$CurrentDisplayName = (Get-ADuser -Identity $CurrentUserName -Properties DisplayName).DisplayName
$CurrentDistinguishedName = (Get-ADuser -Identity $CurrentUserName -Properties DistinguishedName).DistinguishedName
$CurrentUserPrincipalName = (Get-ADuser -Identity $CurrentUserName -Properties UserPrincipalName).UserPrincipalName
```

Comment: Could the problem be that you should be using `Surname` instead of `LastName`?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo here.  I'm using the correct names in the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any better?

```
$CurrentUserDetails = Get-ADuser -Identity $CurrentUserName -Properties *

$CurrentFirstName,
$CurrentLastName,
$CurrentDisplayName,
$CurrentDistinguishedName,
$CurrentUserPrincipalName =

$CurrentUserDetails.GivenName,
$CurrentUserDetails.Surname,
$CurrentUserDetails.DisplayName,
$CurrentUserDetails.DistinguishedName,
$CurrentUserDetails.UserPrincipalName
```

Comment: This works, but now so does the following"


`$CurrentUserDetails = Get-ADuser -Identity $CurrentUserName -Properties *
Write-Host $CurrentUserDetails.GivenName
Write-Host $CurrentUserDetails.SurName
Write-Host $CurrentUserDetails.DisplayName
Write-Host $CurrentUserDetails.DistinguishedName
Write-Host $CurrentUserDetails.UserPrincipalName`

Answer (score 0):

```
$name = Get-ADuser -Identity $CurrentUserName -Properties * | Select-Object 
Name,Created, LastLogon,GivenName,
SurName,DisplayName,DistinguishedName,UsserPrincipleName
```

This should give you all the objects you want to select